# how do i get words after repeated texts in a line

Tags: tcl

I have the following line in my file

**The image of yours doesnot match the image I had in mind**

I need to find the word image in this line and print the next word succeeding it
i.e I need the following o/p:

*word_1 = of*
*word_2 = I*

I have regexp command to find the word *image* but how can I find words succeeding it without having to use lsearch cmd??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the parameter *-inline* that returns the array of matching.

So you could have an example here:

```
set text "The image of yours doesnot match the image I had in mind"

set i 0
set word_1 ""
set word_2 ""
set words [list ]

foreach {img _get} [regexp -all -inline -- {image ([a-zA-Z]+)} $text] {
  # print out the word after "image"
  puts $_get

  # this if you want to save in a list
  lappend words $_get

  # here you can save on separate variables
  if {$i == 0} {
     set word_1 $_get
  } else {
     set word_2 $_get
  }
  incr i
}
```

Using a list is a more flexible approach, but if you already know the exact number of words that will match the sentence, than the single variables should fit well.

Comment: Can I set it to a variable like below *text1 = of text1 = I*   
    I need to set each word to a variable and use that variable in my script

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
set txt {The image of yours doesnot match the image I had in mind}

set words [split $txt]
for {set i 0} {$i < [llength $words]} {incr i} {
    if {[lindex $words $i] eq "image"} {
        puts [lindex $words [incr i]]
    }
}
```

This solution looks at each word in sequence. If it is equal to "image" it prints the following word and then continues with the next word in the list.

**edit**

To save each found word in a variable and use it immediately, replace `puts [lindex $words [incr i]]` with:

```
        set found [lindex $words [incr i]]
        # do something with $found
```

To save each found word in a list and deal with all the words after finding them all, replace the same line with:

```
        lappend found [lindex $words [incr i]]
```

It's a good idea to set `found` to the empty list before searching for words.

Documentation:
[< (operator)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm),
[eq (operator)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm),
[for](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/for.htm),
[if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm),
[incr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/incr.htm),
[lappend](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lappend.htm),
[lindex](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lindex.htm),
[llength](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/llength.htm),
[puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm)

Comment: Can I set it to a variable like below   *text1 = of*   *text1 = I*  I need to set each word to a variable and use that variable in my script